# Maximal Subgroups and Point Stabilizers of Primitive Group Actions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ acts primitive on a set $\Omega$, then the point stabilizers are maximal subgroups, are all maximal subgroups point stabilizers in this case, and for some group $G$ and a maximal group $L$, is there a permutation group representation such that $L$ is a point stabilizer?

Comment: Yes of course, it's just the action by multiplication on the cosets of $L$ That is true for all subgroups. (Why have you given this the tag "finite-groups"? Why finite in particular?)

Comment: No sorry, just because I am mostly concerned with finite groups and use these concepts connected with finite groups, but of course this is nothing which just works in the finite case, so I removed the tag.

Comment: If one of your question is "If $G$ acts primitively on a set $\Omega$, is it true that all maximal subgroups are point stabilizers (with respect to that particular action)?", then the answer is "in general, no" . In the finite case, the answer is always "no", because the maximal subgroups cannot all be conjugate, by a counting argument. And the point stabilizers of a transitive action are all conjugate.